# Does not recognize field in Ecto migration, even after flush

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm following something similar to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44098069/how-to-update-field-value-dynamically-in-ecto-migration), by adding a field and populating it in a migration.

```
def up do
  alter table(:posts) do
    add :urltitle, :string
  end

  flush()

  Repo.all(Post)
  |> Enum.map(fn p ->
       urltitle =
         p.title
         |> String.downcase
         |> Enum.map(fn c -> case URI.char_unreserved?(c) do
                               true -> c
                               false -> '-'
                             end
                     end)
         |> to_string
       Ecto.Changeset.cast(p, %{urltitle: urltitle}, ~w(urltitle))
     end)
  |> Repo.update_all()
end
```

With the flush(), it still has problems recognizing my new field :urltitle. The error message I get is

> (ArgumentError) unknown field `urltitle`. Only fields, embeds and associations (except :through ones) are supported in changesets

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Did you add that field to your schema definition of `Post`?

Comment: no, I did not. There's a problem with update_all (I tried update_all([]) like in the second answer but that also did not work. I guess this specific question has been resolved though. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a problem with the table not having the column. You forgot to add the field to your schema definition.